# TypeScript conditional types not compiling

Tags: typescript

Why does the following typescript not compile without errors?

```js
const conditionalTypedFunction =
  (inputArg: string | string []):
    typeof inputArg extends string ? string : string[] 
  => {
    return inputArg;
  }
```

Here is a link to the TypeScript Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYBMCWUngIYBsAqBPADgKYIBiArmMKuDALwwAUSY+ZUAggE4DmAXDNE7NuMAD4CoQsCIDaAXQCU-KAUIgAZjGasOPGIQAeUQoggSpIgPznhMfoOHy6APhgBvALAAoGL5idCKDJOMC0WNi5uAG5vAF9vIA

I know that function overloads are an option. But I don't want to use them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `inputArg` is an *Union Type* `string | string []`, the condition `typeof inputArg extends string` always yields **false**.
So, to TypeScript the function is always supposed to return a `string[]`.

[image]

[image]

**## EDIT / ADD ##**

I added a link to this playground in the comments

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. ... Is there a way to solve this then without function overloads? I want the inputArg to be only of type string or string[] and the output type to be the same as inputArg when using the function.

Comment: @philkunz You can use a generic to 'carry' the input type to the return type: `const myFunction = <T extends string | string[]>(inputArg: T): T { ... }`. See [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYBMCWUngIYBsAqBPADgKYIBiArmMKuDALwwA82MhAHlIYhDNAE5JgA5jAA+PKPyEwA2gF0AfAAoB+MlACCvQQC4Y2AJS7mteTADeAWABQMWzF6EoZXmBgq1mwQG5rAX2tAA)

Comment: Whats strange though, that this doesn't work then: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYBMCWUngIYBsAqBPADgKYIBiArmMKuDALwwA82MhAHlIYhDNAE5JgA5jAA+PKPyEwA2gF0AfAAoB+MlACCvQQC4Y2AJS7mteTADeAWABQMWzCQAzGIqgFCIJyrWbhtPzAByPgFBAP1zazsomF5CKDJeMECAC0JMTBAAgG5IuwBfXNtY+MT7MFUNLRyrAqtreGgYwggyTFh6eGRqMCw8IlIKKjQwRQDU9Mz9ayA

Comment: @philkunz https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwIL3gQxAB4AVKCAD2AmQBMBnKOhFVKAH0ebQG0BdAPigBeKKQpVaDJkjRQA-JxmsAXIpZ8A3ACgtAYwD2yJlAO1EwRIbwAbYuAg0AYgFdkui4eFQoAChRhnYBxUVWkWdjUeXgBKVTglTBx8IlBIfQAzKH9A4MEhQQBvLW9vREyfVIgMrOQAoPhWISaoAHIwtBboqCKS3qh4CGBneGRWgAsIa2t9Fu1egF9ikoGhkZq64O1FvUM6fWsIADpp1B9TGnNLZBs7SCdXdyufFompmejonaN9o5OzwwuHmutns9zcQJ83Bek2mLQANK1UIh4NY6C0Yp8lkA

Comment: @cheesyMan See, type inference still doesn't work. The assigned variables still are of type string | string[], regardless of the input. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwIL3gQxAB4AVKCAD2AmQBMBnKOhFVKAH0ebQG0BdAPigBeKKQpVaDJkjRQA-JxmsAXIpZ8A3ACgtAYwD2yJlAO1EwRIbwAbYuAg0AYgFdkui4eFQoAChRhnYBxUVWkWdjUeXgBKVTglTBx8IlBIfQAzKH9A4MEhQQBvLW9vREyfVIgMrOQAoPhWISaoAHIwtBboqCKS3qh4CGBneGRWgAsIa2t9Fu1egF9ikoGhkZq64O1FvUNjOjH9Z2saACEIePCRUxpzS2QbO0gnV3c7nxaJqZnonaNgRgOR1OECSBC811uVls9mebg8yB83A+k2mLQANK1UIh4NY6C0YlogA

Comment: @philkunz it's normal TS behavior. If you define a function returning Union type, returned values will be of same Union type too, regardless of real returned value type:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgEMAnAc0QC4iwBPASkpShJjAoB9EwQ0AjDCUSIA3gChhwmMAJRaABwxxgiUhQC8mxAHJkLNmW31REyWZIYoIEkgBEUABYxkiZ6uat2tgNynhAX0QMABtkDGFxM3NLayQARgAGBN8zfzE0sQgEPUQAQUR1FHRsXFgEAm01I18ssByAIQKizBxIMsIAJnpfIA

Here both **A** and **B** will be of type `string | number`, even if the function clearly says that **A** will be a string and **B** will be a number

Comment: Ok but the TS docs clearly imply that this should be possible? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

However they skirt around things by not providing an actual example, instead throwing an error within the function